# Ensure that the service is automatically started immediately after installation

Tags: c#, service, installutil

I have a windows service that i am installing using installutil.exe. How can i ensure that the service is automatically started immediately after installation. This is the service ProjectInstaller class

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MedicalService_WindowsService
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ServiceInstaller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Set the `StartType` to [Automatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicestartmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will ensure the service starts automatically, but does not actually starts the service. To do that, after the installation of the service is complete, start the service explicitly using [ServiceController.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb9w7ytd.aspx).